# Why does django page cms get_absolute_url return an empty string?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views, django-cms

I am having issues with get_absolute_url in my django templates when using django page cms.
It returns an empty string and does not link to my required page.

I have the following Models, URLs templates and views

Models

```
class Body(models.Model):
...
url = models.SlugField(unique=True, help_text='---')
```

urls

```
(r'^news/', include('news.urls_news')),......

url(r'^/(?P<url>[\w\-]+)/$', 'news_view', name='news_view'),
```

View

```
def news_view(request, url):
new = get_object_or_404(Body, url=url)
return render_to_response('news/view.html', {
    'news': news
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
   <li><a href="{{ news.get_absolute_url }}">{{ news.title }}</a></li>
```

the following code in my template returns the string I desire however this does to direct to my html page

```
   <li><a href="{{ news.url }}">{{ news.title }}</a></li>
```

I know my everything links to the correct files because I have other views that work correctly. Could somebody please point me in the correct direction as to why get_absolute_url is not working correctly and why {{ news.url }} does not direct to the correct page. I am sure it has something to do with my urls.py however I am not certain.
Please bear with me I am new to django. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually defined a `get_absolute_url` method on the News model? You don't show it.

Comment: Yes it was that coupled with the fact I had ordered my URLs in the wrong order. I did not think that the ordering of URLS mattered however it does. cheers.